# Generic type annotation of multi-dimensional array with index-dependent types of elements

Tags: typescript

Here is 2d array; the first child of array is always number, and second - always string.
How to annotate is value via generic?

```
const sample: Array<Array</* ??? */>> = [ [1, "alpha" ], [2, "bravo" ]];
```

Comment: Looks like you want an array of [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) types like `Array<[number, string]>`. If that doesn't work for you, please elaborate.  Good luck!

Comment: Works! I thought it will be `Array<Array<[number, string]>>` by second `Array` is redundant. Thank you for the comment answer!

Comment: @GurebuBokofu the `[number, string]` notation is for a tuple. Yes, that *happens* to be an array but it's distinct from the array notation in TypeScript. `Array<T>` (or `T[]` which is the same thing) means "any amount of `T` values". So `Array<string>` could be an empty array, it might have 4 values or 9000. It's unconstrained. `[number, string]` is *always* going to be two values and it's *always* the same types at each position. `Array<[number, string]>` means any amount of these tuples. `Array<Array<[number, string]>>` means you have an array which holds *other arrays* that hold tuples.

Comment: @VLAZ, thank you for the explanation, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this signature:

```
type tuple = [number, string];
const sample: Array<Array<Tuple>> = [ [1, "alpha" ], [2, "bravo" ]];
```